# showing array data in single row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to show my array list data with same id into a single row of data like this:
[image]

I get my array like this:

```
Collection {#308 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#303 ▼
      +"bill_no": "12334"
      +"company_name": "sacacas"
      +"contact": "0770230006"
      +"payment": 250.0
      +"installment_method": 1
      +"date": "2019-03-20 00:00:00"
    }
    1 => {#301 ▼
      +"bill_no": "12334"
      +"company_name": "sacacas"
      +"contact": "0770230006"
      +"payment": 250.0
      +"installment_method": 2
      +"date": "2019-03-27 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to show same bill no data like this table with installement method type and payment. I want to get if same bill no has then show all array data into a single row like above picture I noted. Can anyone help me?

This is the query I'm using:

```
$sales = DB::table('sales')
    ->join('installments', 'sales.bill_no', '=', 'installments.bill_no')
    ->select('sales.bill_no', 'sales.company_name', 'sales.contact', 'installments.payment', 'installments.installment_method', 'installments.date')
    ->where('sales.status', '=', 'pending')
    ->where('installments.status', '=', 'paid')
    ->orderBy('sales.bill_no')
    ->get();
```

Comment: it sound like group by or array_map .. what is installement in table and how you need to show them both in one column?

Comment: @daremachine i want to show if installment method is 1 then payment 1 column and installment method is 2 then show payment 2 column and their paid price and date

Comment: @daremachine i mentioned a table picture what i want to show structure

Comment: can you share the code how you form this json. if it is a query, share it please

Comment: @Sandeep Sudhakaran                                                                                                 
   `$sales = DB::table('sales')
                ->join('installments', 'sales.bill_no', '=', 'installments.bill_no')
                ->select('sales.bill_no','sales.company_name', 'sales.contact', 'installments.payment', 'installments.installment_method', 'installments.date')
                ->where('sales.status', '=', 'pending')
                ->where('installments.status', '=', 'paid')
                ->orderBy('sales.bill_no')
                ->get();`

Comment: Edit your question with code of blade file and how do you output it now.

Comment: @Tpojka i have no idea about code to view this kind of table. i want to  from you guys

Comment: Sorry, error or didn't happen. Stack Overflow is not free coding service. But it can be expected as helping resource for solving errors. You didn't show us your effort in solving issue and error you're facing during that attempt. Check [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) article of how to ask question that will be answered probably. Start studying HTML and particularly tables.

Comment: @Tpojka i tried with above model code. but i have no idea with how to show seperate payment dates in join table

Comment: I don't see any html there. For displaying table data you need html with [table](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp), right?